# CERN ROOT framework segmentation fault with visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, root-framework

I am trying to use CERN's ROOT framework inside a Visual C++ project.

I built it from sources using the following commands (https://root.cern/releases/release-62606/):

``

`cmake -G"Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 -Thost=x64 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=..\install_dir ..\root_src`

`cmake --build . --config Debug --target install`

`git clone --branch latest-stable --depth=1 https://github.com/root-project/root.git root_src`

I then tried to build an example to test if my setup worked.

```cpp
#include "TF1.h"
#include "TApplication.h"
#include "TCanvas.h"
#include "TRootCanvas.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    TApplication app("app", &argc, argv); // Seg fault happens with this line
    TCanvas* c = new TCanvas("c", "Something", 0, 0, 800, 600);
    TF1* f1 = new TF1("f1", "sin(x)", -5, 5);
    f1->SetLineColor(kBlue + 1);
    f1->SetTitle("My graph;x; sin(x)");
    f1->Draw();
    c->Modified(); c->Update();
    TRootCanvas* rc = (TRootCanvas*)c->GetCanvasImp();
    rc->Connect("CloseWindow()", "TApplication", gApplication, "Terminate()");
    app.Run();
    return 0;
}
```

When I build this code and run it, I get a segmentation fault.

```
Critical error detected c0000374
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF29FEF609 (ntdll.dll) in RootTest.exe: 0xC0000374: Un segment de mémoire a été endommagé (parameters: 0x00007FFF2A0597F0).
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF29FEF609 (ntdll.dll) in RootTest.exe: 0xC0000374: Un segment de mémoire a été endommagé (parameters: 0x00007FFF2A0597F0).

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF29F0EC5C (ntdll.dll) in RootTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF29F0EC5C (ntdll.dll) in RootTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF29F0EC5C (ntdll.dll) in RootTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF29F0EC5C (ntdll.dll) in RootTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF29F0EC5C (ntdll.dll) in RootTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF29F0EC5C (ntdll.dll) in RootTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF29F0EC5C (ntdll.dll) in RootTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.

The program '[28120] RootTest.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Visual Studio tells me that the error comes from `TWinNTSystem.cxx` line 1017

`while (buf[0] && GetFileAttributes(check_path.Data()) == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) {`

I use `/sdl-`, `/permissive` and `/std=c++17`.

Do you have any idea why I am having this segmentation fault ?

Comment: Cam you try to mimimize your example further, so that only the lines are in there that are required to get the error?

Comment: With only the first line in the main I got the same error. It comes from the initialization of the TApplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%ROOTSYS%` must be set else ROOT won't be able to find `%ROOTSYS/etc` directory.

This can be achieved by running `thisroot.bat`.

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)